# "I saw one of my classmates who was/were?"

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

Which one is correct? Please explain.

> I saw one of my classmates who was also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

> I saw one of my classmates who were also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

In this sentence what is the subject and why? How can I find the subject in sentences like this?

Comment: One is singular (of course!), so use 'was'. Also on a boat.

Comment: (A) One of your classmates happened to be a passenger on the boat. (B) A group of your classmates were on board the boat, and at a particular moment you saw one of them. In both cases, the subject is 'I' (because you did the seeing).

Comment: If you're referring to the group of classmates, then a comma is necessary because then it would be a non-defining clause. The subject of the sentence certainly is "I", but this question is about the subordinate clause, in which the subject changes.

Comment: Are you asking what the subject is or whether the verb should be singular or plural?

Comment: Yes, @BillJ I want to know what the subject is and whether the verb should be singular or plural?

Comment: I want to know which one is correct was or were and why? If both of them correct then are those grammatically accurate?

Comment: The subject can only be "I"; the rest is the predicate. The natural interpretation is that the relative clause belongs in the topmost noun phrase with "one" as head, not the one with "classmates" as head. There was a set of classmates who were on the boat and you saw one member of that set, and hence the verb should be the singular "was".

Comment: Is there any way we can use were without making any grammatical mistake?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

**This has to do with whether this is a defining or non-defining clause.**

> I saw one of my classmates who was also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

In this case, who is defining "one of my classmates". With "who was also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin" you are saying which classmate you are referring to.

> I saw one of my classmates who were also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

This sentence is incorrect the way it is currently written. If you re-write with a comma, then you get a non-defining clause, which means you're adding extra information. Since you're adding extra information it could be about both the "one" classmate from the group or about the group of "classmates".

> I saw one of my classmates, who were also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

Please notice the comma. This sentence would be perfectly correct because you are just adding information about the other "classmates" in your sentence.

> I saw one of my classmates, who was also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin.

This sentence is also fine, but it is not clear which classmate you are talking about. We don't know which one he was, all we know is that he was also on the boat.

**P.S. There was a missing article "the" before the word "boat". I added the article in my explanation.

Comment: I don't see that it has anything to do with whether it is a defining or non-defining relative clause.

Comment: "I saw one of my classmates, who were also on the boat while travelling to Saint Martin." Are you saying that this sentence doesn't work?