# One of my family members was or were?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural, subjects

"One of my family members were/was sick last night."

In this sentence should I use was or were? Please explain. Which one is subject and why? Please explain with detailed information. I am having trouble with sentences like this.

Comment: Isn't this the exact same question as https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/280499/one-of-my-classmates-who-was-were ?

Comment: Yes it is maybe but I have a sheet where they used different answer. In this above sentence he used was and the question you mentioned he used were. I am really confused. That's why I want to know the difference.

Comment: You should use "was". The head of the noun phrase is the singular "one" and this determines the number of the verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was *all* your family members who were sick, they would be the subject, the subject would be plural and you would need "were".

**BUT**

What is the word "**ONE**" doing?

Only **ONE of them** was sick. So he or she is the subject, the subject is singular and you need "was".

Past tense of the verb **be**:

SINGULAR
I was
You were
He/She/It was

PLURAL
We were
You were
They were